# How to extract entities from 'bot sends' in wit.ai

Tags: python-3.x, wit.ai

I have a scenario like this

```
User says: What's the temperature in SF?
bot executes: get_forecast
updates context with: forecast
bot send: {forecast}
```

Is there a way to use {forecast} and extract entities from it? For example, I can continue the above story as -

```
User say: convert that in celsius
<extract temperature from {forecast} set entities>
bot execute: convert_to_celsius
updates context with: temperature
bot sends: {temperature}
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: The temperature should be available in the context of the next request, right? Can, you just parse the string in the convert action then send it back as the forecast again?

Answer (score 0):

The entity value can be stored in context, or on your backend/server.

If you store {forecast} in context, when user request conversion to celsius, you retrieve it from context, convert it and update context with {temperature}.

However, note that 'context' is passed around between user and your backend so I do not recommend putting too many unnecessary values in it, due to more data being transmitted for each call.

For your use case, you could storing {forecast} on your server instead. When user request conversion, simply retrieve it and update context.